# python library and example for gmail smtp using oauth2

Tags: python, gmail, oauth-2.0

The [python oauth2 library](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) seems to implement oauth 1.0 protocol.
The `import oauth2 as oauth` is misleading, most probably it is referred to the 2nd version of the python lib implementing oauth 1.0.

Is there any python library implementing the oauth 2.0 protocol?
and also sample for using it.

i tried google but failed to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really give a try to [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth). It supports OAuth 1.0/a and 2.0